# How to get width of mobile browser window when its zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I tried first with the viewport meta tag but it isn´t worked. Then I tried with 
screen.availWidth but it didnt worked too.

Comment: Show us the code you tried...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
   window.onscroll = function() {
       console.log(this.innerWidth)
   }
```

See [Window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  console.log(this.innerWidth)
};
```

```css
body {
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code. window.outerWidth gives width including scrollbars.  read [this document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_outerheight.asp)

```
window.onscroll = function() {
   var w = window.outerWidth;
}
```